# Find the first larger value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, find

I have a sorted array of float numbers ranging from 0 to 1.
The goal is to generate a random number (r) between the same range and determine between which two numbers from the array (r) lie.
I tried "(np.abs(array - value)).argmin()" but it gives the nearest number which sometimes is the larger one and others is the smaller one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take an example of a random number

```
import numpy as np
# Generate a random number between 0 and 1
r = np.random.rand()
# create a sorted array
a = np.arange(20)/20
# create an array of the same element r repeated to match the size of a
n = (np.repeat(r, 20) >= a).sum()
# you can get the interval like this
a[n-1:n+1]
```